# Latest Outlook "Edit Recurrence" control-id

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, recurrence, fluent-ui

Within an Outlook Addin I am currently capturing when a user clicks the Recurrence Button for Series using this XML:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
    <commands>
        <command idMso="Recurrence" onAction="RecurrenceButtonClick"/>
        <command idMso="RecurrenceExplorer" onAction="RecurrenceButtonClick"/>
    </commands>
</customUI>
```

Now there is this new Button in the latest Outlook Versions that I cannot capture:

[image]

I have not found the control-id in the Excels provided by Microsoft:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and why?

Comment: When an Appointment is linked to our system and users use our Addin, we want to stop them from changing recurrence of existing series. We do this right now by using the onAction callback for the Recurrence Buttons in the Ribbon.